# Insert UTF-8 txt file into MySql results in ErrorCode 1366

Tags: mysql, encoding, insert, utf, error-code

I am trying to insert a delimited txt file into MySQL but it seems there is something wrong with the encoding.  I get Error coe 1366:Incorrect string value in in MYSQL when I try and insert.  When I open the txt file it looks like this on the line that caused the error.

[image]

Any idea how can I insert this data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters. Something like `\'` for quote and so on

Answer (score 0):

Somehow hex `9C` got into the file.  In latin1, that is `œ`.

Plan A:

Edit the file to remove it.  The text around there is all in uppercase English, so I suspect it was not supposed to be `œ`.

Plan B:

Use the charset option to set the incoming stream to `latin1`.  Then deal with `œ` later (or not).